# Flutter Stops screen recording but the voice is still recorded

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-packages

I just used flutter package flutter_windowmanager to stop screen recording and screenshots the app works properly but when i record screen it appears black screen but the voice is still running

i tried to stop screen recording it worked but the voice is still working

Answer (score 0):

You can check this article for disabling the audio in `Android`:

[Link of the article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/07/capturing-audio-in-android-q.html)

Comment: it did not work for me can you give me and example code